# Acortar código de progressBar en android

Tags: java, android, imagen

Tengo el siguiente código, que me funciona bien:

```
final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, 
PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(imageView);
```

Pero tengo muchas muchas imágenes por lo tanto necesito reemplazar el código que se encuentra dentro de listener.

```
GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() { ALGO AQUI
            })
            .into(imageView);
```

O si se puede de la siguiente forma también:

```
GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .listener(ALGO AQUI)
            .into(imageView);
```

Quiero reemplazar todo este código por ALGO AQUI, ese algo puede ser una variable u otra cosa.

```
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer? AYUDA POR FAVOR.

Comment: cada imagen va a tener su progressbar? no me parece una buena idea, normalmente se usa un placeholder para las imagenes que aún no cargan.

Comment: Yo quería poner un progressbar en cada imagen (porque creo que se ve más elegante mientras se carga la imagen), en lugar de poner una imagen estática en placeholder. La otra opción era colocar un gif en placeholder, pero no lee los archivos GIF en placeholder. ¿Alguna otra opción?

Comment: así como lo estás haciendo no te funciona?

Comment: revisa este tutorial : https://medium.com/@mr.johnnyne/how-to-use-glide-v4-load-image-with-progress-update-eb02671dac18

Comment: Pudiste solucionar esto?